# Jax - Debugging NaN-values

Tags: python, nan, recurrent-neural-network, jax

Nice evening everyone,

i spent the last 6 hours trying to debug seemingly randomly occuring NaN-values in Jax.
I have narrowed down that the NaNs initially stem from either the loss-function or its gradient.

A **minimal-notebook that reproduces the error** is available here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uXa-igMm9QBOOl8ZNdK1OkwxRFlLqvZD?usp=sharing

This might also be interesting as a use-case for Jax. I use Jax to solve an **orientation estimation task** when only a limited amount of gyro-/acc-measurements is available. Here an efficient implementation of quaternion-operations is nice.

The training-loop starts off fine but eventually diverges

```py
Step 0| Loss: 4.550444602966309 | Time: 13.910547971725464s
Step 1| Loss: 4.110116481781006 | Time: 5.478027105331421s
Step 2| Loss: 3.7159230709075928 | Time: 5.476970911026001s
Step 3| Loss: 3.491917371749878 | Time: 5.474078416824341s
Step 4| Loss: 3.232130765914917 | Time: 5.433410406112671s
Step 5| Loss: 3.095140218734741 | Time: 5.433837413787842s
Step 6| Loss: 2.9580295085906982 | Time: 5.429029941558838s
Step 7| Loss: nan | Time: 5.427825689315796s
Step 8| Loss: nan | Time: 5.463077545166016s
Step 9| Loss: nan | Time: 5.479652643203735s
```

This can be traced back by diverging gradients as can be seen from the following snippet

```py
(loss, _), grads = loss_fn(params, X[0], y[0], rnn.reset_carry(bs=2))

grads["params"]["Dense_0"]["bias"] # shape=(bs, out_features)
DeviceArray([[-0.38666773,         nan, -1.0433975 ,         nan],
             [ 0.623061  , -0.20950513,  0.8459796 , -0.42356613]],            dtype=float32)
```

#### My question is: How to debug this?

##### Enabling NaN-debugging

Enabling nan-debugging did not really help as it only ended up leading to huge stacktraces with many hidden traces ..

```py
from jax.config import config
config.update("jax_debug_nans", True)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried to disable the jit compilation via `config.update('jax_disable_jit', True)`, so that you could debug your code with any IDEs and without hidden traces.

Comment: Good to know that the JIT-compilation actually causes the hidden traces, i was wondering about that. Will give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

A few approaches (decently documented in the main docs) may work:

1. As a hotfix, switching to `float64` can do the trick. More info [here](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#nans): `jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)`
2. Gradient Clipping is All You Need ([docs](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Custom_derivative_rules_for_Python_code.html#gradient-clipping))
3. You can sometimes [implement your own backprop](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Custom_derivative_rules_for_Python_code.html#numerical-stability), this can help when e.g. you combine 2 functions that saturate into one that doesn't, or to enforce values at singularities.
4. Diagnose your backprop by inspecting the computational graph. Usually look for divisions, signaled with the `div` token:

```py
from jax import make_jaxpr

# If grad_fn(x) gives you trouble, you can inspect the computation as follows:
grad_fn = jit(value_and_grad(my_forward_prop, argnums=0))
make_jaxpr(grad_fn)(x)
```

Note that the community is quite active and some support has been and is being added to diagnose `NaNs`:

- The ["jax_debug_nans"](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/475) config flag
- More [threads](https://github.com/google/jax/issues?q=is%3Aissue+nan)

Hope this helps!
Andres